# Is there any documentation to convert between docker commands and docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

There are people asking for specific conversions from docker to docker-compose.yml ( [Need to convert this relatively simple docker pull and run commands into a docker-compose.yml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509099/need-to-convert-this-relatively-simple-docker-pull-and-run-commands-into-a-docke/35517428) ) but I wonder if there is any proper documentation.

I've also been looking around for docker-compose.yml files and I find different ways to do things, not knowing if they are actually the exact same thing or not:

In mysql the config is:

```
environment:
 - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress_db
 - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=asdasdas
```

And in phpmyadmin is:

```
environment:
  MYSQL_USERNAME: root
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdasdas
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: Maybe start with [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment)?

Comment: Docker documentation is quite good and extensive. Also yes there are two formats to define env variables, which is documented https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment

Answer (score 0):

Environment can be used in similar way in docker and docker-compose.

Environment names which you try to use doesn't connect with docker and docker-compose command and configuratins, this are connected with images which you try to use.

So which names of environment you should use you should find in documentation (or source) of docker image.

Propably In your examples:
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

I don't know which phpmyadmin image you are using.